# Hibernate does not pick up @Id annotation at getter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

## Problem

In my current project I get this `AnnotationException`:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: my.package.EntityClass

## Defective Code

The problem is caused by the `@Id` annotation, which I moved from the field to the getter:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class EntityClass extends BaseEntityClass {

  private long id;

  @Override
  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "FOOBAR_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_MY_TABLE", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "FOOBAR_GENERATOR")
  public long getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

}
```

## Working Code

When I annotate the `id` attribute instead, it works fine:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class EntityClass extends BaseEntityClass {

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "FOOBAR_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_MY_TABLE", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "FOOBAR_GENERATOR")
  private long id;

  @Override
  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  public long getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

}
```

## Reference to Documentation

The [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e535) states:

> By default the access type of a class hierarchy is defined by the position of the @Id or @EmbeddedId annotations. If these annotations are on a field, then only fields are considered for persistence and the state is accessed via the field. If there annotations are on a getter, then only the getters are considered for persistence and the state is accessed via the getter/setter. That works well in practice and is the recommended approach.

## Question

My class has additional attributes, where **I want to annotate the getters**. So I need to put the `@Id` annotation at the getter as well.

This worked fine in other projects before, but this time Hibernate seems to not pick up the entity's identifier, when the getter is annotated.

- Is there any additional configuration property I have to change?
- Or did this behavious change between Hibernate versions?

Comment: is id the only field on that entity? if there are others, do they have annotations on getters also?

Comment: As mentioned in my question, there are more fields and ultimately, I want to have all annotations at the getters. But this does not work, unless Hibernate picks up the ``@Id`` annotation at the getter.

Comment: Could you please post the implementation of the `BaseEntityClass` class?

Answer (score 1):

You need to consistently use `@Id` on all the getters only then. Make sure no fields are annotated with `@Id` instead of getters. Mixing and matching will stop it working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` annotation on your entity like this?

```java
import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class EntityClass extends BaseEntityClass {
...
}
```